# Python: How to Access Linux Paths

Tags: python, linux, path

Using Python, how does one parse/access files with Linux-specific features, like `"~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default"`?  I've tried this, but it doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "parse"? What Linux-specific features are you referring to? What have you tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This

```
import glob, os
glob.glob(os.path.expanduser('~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default'))
```

will give you a list of all files ending in ".default" in the current user's `~/.mozilla/firefox` directory using [os.path.expanduser](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) to expand the `~` in the path and [glob.glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html#glob.glob) to match the `*.default` file pattern.

Comment: Thanks!  That's perfect.  Then I can use $your_code[0] and get any files I want in that directory.

Sorry I can't vote up your answer, I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 2):

`~` is expanded by the shell and not a real path. As such you have to navigate there manually.

```
import os

homeDir = os.environ['HOME']
f = open( homeDir + '/.mozilla/firefox/*.default' )
# ...
```

Comment: That doesn't quite work.  The asterisk is a wild card, not a part of the name.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot.

Incidently this method also works for writing a new file to the $HOME path.
i.e

import os

directoryPath = os.environ['HOME']
file = open(directoryPath + "/newFile.csv", "w")

Answer (score 2):

It's important to remember:

- use of the tilde `~` expands the home directory as per Poke's answer
- use of the forward slash `/` is the separator for linux / *nix directories
- by default, *nix systems such as linux for example has a wild card globbing in the shell, for instance `echo *.*` will return back all files that match the asterisk dot asterisk (as per Will McCutcheon's answer!)

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.python.org/library/os.html
Gives a complete reference if you would like to change directory or give paths.

You can for example give relative paths and access specific files.

If you would like to execute commands then http://docs.python.org/library/commands.html provides nice wrappers for the os.popen() function